# Android - Create links using TextView

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, linkify

I want to make my TextView as link which can open Web Pages, but the text visible to user is different than the original link. I know how to create links using linkify but it displays the link in the TextView. 
P.S. I am a beginner, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: android:autoLink="web" this is properties of TextView

Comment: where to specify the url?

Comment: in android:text="www.google.co.in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='link here'> text here </a>"));
 textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`